# memory problems mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having problems updating a mysql database. 
I want to run this script on a ~800,000 row database but my memory runs out after 5 rows so some how I need to automatically update this mysql query by adding +5 to the LIMIT.

I want to use a redirect or reset the memory somehow..

```
<?php

    include(dirname(__FILE__) .'/include/simple_html_dom.php');

    mysql_connect('localhost', '', '');
    mysql_select_db('');

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT gamertag FROM gamertags LIMIT 0, 5 ");
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $gamertag = $row['gamertag'];

            //pages to pull stats from
            $site_url = 'http://www.bungie.net';
            $stats_page = 'http://www.bungie.net/stats/reach/default.aspx?player=';

            //create dom
            $html = new simple_html_dom();
            $html->load_file($stats_page . urlencode(strtolower($gamertag)));

            //pull nameplate emblem url, ****if it exist****
            $nameplate_emblem_el = $html->find("#ctl00_mainContent_identityBar_namePlateImg");
            if (!$nameplate_emblem_el){
                $nameplate_emblem = 'No nameplate emblem!';
            }
            else{
                //only if #ctl00_mainContent_identityBar_namePlateImg is found
                $nameplate_emblem = htmlspecialchars_decode($nameplate_emblem_el[0]->attr['src']);
                $nameplate_emblem = $site_url . $nameplate_emblem;
            }   

            mysql_query("INSERT IGNORE INTO star SET gamertag = '".$gamertag."',nameplate = '".$nameplate_emblem."'");
        }

?>
```

Comment: WHy do you need to select all 800 000 rows? Just out of curiosity. IF you need to update all of them somehow wouldn't it be possible to do it via the query?

Comment: You will need to show more code so we can see what uses the memory

Comment: Maybe you could show us the rest of your script or explain us what the aim of this. Prefer mysql_fetch_row() if you only need the gamertag it is faster and less resource consuming.

Comment: @Unicron - added the entire script

Comment: you have while loop but you are not closing it

Comment: LOL Halo Reach player ;) I used simple_html_dom which is really great, but extremely slow and resource consuming.. Especially with bungie.net which slow too.. If your update is punctual, you could make loops though auto-reloading the page passing in GET params the new LIMIT $_GET['limit'], $_GET['limit']+5; but of course this a pity solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

800.000 is a large number, not sure if it´s gonna happen, but from a comments on php manual:
"unset() does just what it's name says - unset a variable. It does not force immediate memory freeing. PHP's garbage collector will do it when it see fits - by intention as soon, as those CPU cycles aren't needed anyway, or as late as before the script would run out of memory, whatever occurs first.

If you are doing $whatever = null; then you are rewriting variable's data. You might get memory freed / shrunk faster, but it may steal CPU cycles from the code that truly needs them sooner, resulting in a longer overall execution time."

source:http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php

So, try to unset/set to null the variables after each time the loop runs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you hit your php memory limit, and not the machines.  If so, you can edit php.ini (typically /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini) to give more memory to php.  Look for "memory_limit = X" where X is something like 256M